# Does Narcos use real corpses?

Tags: film-techniques, narcos

I was looking through Netflix and saw the Colombian druglord themed series called Narcos, it looked interesting so I checked out the details, where I saw this:

[image: Narcos Netflix maturity rating: strong violence, strong language, sex, nudity, real corpses, drug theme]

While I can imagine that using a real corpse is a very true to life (no pun intended) way to show death, I always assumed that using a real body on set would be impossible due to things like the possible smell and squeamish actors, even without the potential moral dilemma.

Is this accurate? Does Narcos actually use real corpses for bodies?

(I haven't watch the show yet, so if the corpses are in fact in some historical images or similar then forgive my assumptions)

Comment: When I die, I can leave my body to Netflix!?

Comment: From what I understand, they wanted to use real corpses, but the corpses refused to sign the appropriate waivers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been working my way through Narcos. I haven't seen the entire season yet but in the 5 episodes I've watched so far the show is a blend of real archival pieces (video clips, photographs, etc) with scenes filmed for the show with the actors. The only real corpses I've seen have been in the archival materials.

Comment: It does add an incredible sense of poignancy, seeing a situation go down and then see the _real life_ aftermath.